# array_count_values for Specific Keys in Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [color_object] => blue
    [color_1] => green
    [color_2] => blue
    [color_3] => blue
    [color_4] => red
    [color_5] => purple
    [AltColor] => blue
)
```

I can use `array_count_values` and it will give me the count for `blue` as `4`.

But I need to only count the values within specific keys of the array, in this example I need to limit my count to the `color_1` `color_2` `color_3` `color_4` and `color_5` only.

Is it possible to only count the instances of `blue` within specified keys, giving me a desired result of `2`?

PHP code:

```
$array = array("id"=>"1", "color_object"=>"blue", "color_1"=>"green", "color_2"=>"blue", "color_3"=>"blue", "color_4"=>"red", "color_5"=>"purple", "AltColor"=>"blue");
```

Comment: Make another array with just those keys.

Comment: Why do you have separate `color_1`, `color_2`, etc. elements? Why not make it an array `'colors' => array('green', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'purple', 'blue')`

Comment: In general, whenever you find yourself creating numbered variables or keys like that, you should probably be using an array instead.

Comment: The actual array I am working with is one returned from `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. I was trying to minimize the question, and I don't think I have as much control over the array as my question implied.  Can you suggest a function reference to look into? I think maybe creating another array with just those keys might work in this instance.

Comment: I just supplied the manually created PHP code so I could provide a code example to work with.

Comment: just select the columns that you need, `select col1, col2, col3, coln...` then make you array count values

Comment: That could work.. except then I would have to make two queries for the same info (I need all the columns in my query, just need to count the specific columns). I was under the impression that trying to parse the info with php with my one query would be best. Not sure if this would "over complicate" things or not.

Comment: Yeah, @Ghost, on second thought I don't think this would be ideal, as I'm having to do JOINS on other tables and columns to get them aligned correctly.  Something in PHP would be preferable.

Comment: @Barmar, I think your solution was best I've found so far, in creating array with just those keys.  In essence, defining variables for my columns `$color_1 = $rs['color_1']` `$color_2 = $rs['color_2']` etc. then creating an array from those variables and doing a count. I am going to mess with this lots more tomorrow but thank you it is a huge help!

Comment: I had a feeling this was coming from a database, and this suggests poor normalization. Instead of having 5 color columns, you should have 1-to-many color table.

Comment: Okay, I will look into this. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: As for the solution to this question, was pretty easy and seems to be holding up well. Just did `$colorarray = array($color_1, $color_2);` and then `$arraycount = array_count_values($colorarray);` and then it returns the number I wanted by doing `$colorcount = $arraycount['blue'];` I'll have to look into 1-to-many tables this weekend when I get more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

    $array = array(
        "id"=>"1",
        "color_object"=>"blue",
        "color_1"=>"green",
        "color_2"=>"blue",
        "color_3"=>"blue",
        "color_4"=>"red",
        "color_5"=>"purple",
        "AltColor"=>"blue"
    );

    $preg = '/^color_\d{1,}/i';

    $callback = function ($val) use($preg) {
        if (preg_match($preg, $val, $match)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }   
    };

    $data = array_filter($array, $callback, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    $result = array_count_values($data);

    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: array_filter($array, $callback, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);     ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY   php version >= 5.6

Comment: Thank you! I'm still maybe looking for something simpler, though. Going to have to do some more research and work on this tomorrow I will accept an answer then.

Comment: Actual solution I used is in the comments of my original post, but I'm going to accept your answer as you were the first to provide a solution to the broader question.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use function `array_sum`
wrap your `array_map` inside it to add just return indexes
that meet your condition

```
$array = Array
(
    'id' => 1,
    'color_code' => 'blue',
    'color_1' => 'green',
    'color_2' => 'blue',
    'color_3' => 'blue',
    'color_4' => 'red',
    'color_25' => 'purple',
    'AltColor' => 'blue',
);

echo "The total count is of index => color and value => blue is ".array_sum(array_map(
    function($value, $key) {
        return (preg_match('/^color_\d{1,}/i', $key) && $value == 'blue') ? true : false;
    }, $array, array_keys($array))
);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/697783)